# Android navigation

Tags: android

I have a question about navigation in android.

A have a frm1(activity) and a frm2(activity).

When I am in frm1, I press some item of a list, and a popup appears, and then the android send me to frm2. And when I press the return button, the android send me to frm1 showing the popup. =( . How can I avoid this(make android show me frm1 without the popup). Maybe you are saying, "so, why dont you do an intent ". The thing is that i dont wanna miss the state of frm1

thanks

this is the code whan i use the intent from frm1 to frm2,

*Onclick function for the list in frm1

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,long arg3){

            AddDebtToTransaction(pos);
        }
    }); 




   @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public void AddDebtToTransaction(final int pos)
    {  
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Ver Detalle", "Agregar a la Transacción"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("¿Qué desea hacer?");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    Intent i2 = new Intent(Frmpayment_searchdebts.this,Frmpayment_transactiondebt.class);
                startActivity(i2);
    });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: If you're not using an Intent, how are you showing frm2?

Comment: hi, thanks fot the reply, When i said that I dont want to use intent, i meant that i dont wanna use it for going to frm1 from frm2

Comment: Got it.  Please post the code where you create the popup and the intent for frm2

Answer (score 1):

You could use `startActivityForResult` when going to frm2 and in frm1 overriding onActivityResult and using `dismissDialog()` in there.
More information can be found here: [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)